# What is the meaning of "release into the circulation large quantities of exosomes"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "release into the circulation large quantities of exosomes" in the following sentences,

> We explain the mechanism by which immune cells ***release into the
> circulation large quantities of exosomes*** containing spike protein
> along with critical microRNAs that induce a signaling response in
> recipient cells at distant sites.

?

(Source: Innate Immune Suppression by SARS-CoV-2 mRNA Vaccinations: The role of G-quadruplexes, exosomes and microRNAs
By Stephanie Seneff, Greg Nigh, Anthony M. Kyriakopoulos, Peter A McCullough )

Does "immune cells ***release into*** the cirulation large quantities of exosomes~" mean " immune cells ***release*** large quantities of exosomes containing spike protein along with critical microRNAs that induce a signaling response in recipient cells at distant sites ***into*** the circulation" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your version of the sentence has the same meaning as the original. You've placed the adverbial phrase "into the circulation" (which modifies the verb "release") after the direct object; that is a typical word order. However, the DO ("large quantities of . . . at distant sites"*) is very long, so the adverbial phrase ends up very far from the verb that it modifes. Thus, the author has moved it closer (before the DO). That happens fairly often in English.

*Note that there are also other ways of parsing this sentence. For example, the prepositional phrase "along with . . . at distant sites" might not modify "containing" but instead modify "release"; in that case, it would not be part of the DO. The author's intended meaning is somewhat unclear.